# reshape dataframe in python using suffix

Tags: python, reshape

I've moved from STATA to Python and wondering if there is an equivalent way of reshaping wide to long using variable suffixes.

Example data

| City. | shp_1km_mean | shp_1km_sd | shp_100m_mean | shp_100m_sd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austin | 5.05 | 1.02 | 7.2 | 3.1 |
| Chicago | 2.17 | .89 | 6.25 | 1.11 |

and I'd like it to look like:

| City | mean | sd | metric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austin | 5.05 | 1.02 | shp_1km_ |
| Austin | 7.2 | 3.1 | shp_100m_ |
| Chicago | 2.17 | .89 | shp_1km_ |
| Chicago | 6.25 | 1.11 | shp_100m_ |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `melt` a dataframe to convert from wide-to-long.

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars='City')
df
       City       variable  value
0   Austin    shp_1km_mean   5.05
1  Chicago    shp_1km_mean   2.17
2   Austin      shp_1km_sd   1.02
3  Chicago      shp_1km_sd   0.89
4   Austin   shp_100m_mean   7.20
5  Chicago   shp_100m_mean   6.25
6   Austin     shp_100m_sd   3.10
7  Chicago     shp_100m_sd   1.11
```

Now you want to pull out the `mean` or `sd` from our new `variable` column, which can be done by making the column a `str` and using `split` and pulling out the third element (so indexed to 2).

```py
df['temp_col'] = df['variable'].str.split('_').str[2]
df
       City       variable  value  temp_col
0   Austin    shp_1km_mean   5.05  mean
1  Chicago    shp_1km_mean   2.17  mean
2   Austin      shp_1km_sd   1.02    sd
3  Chicago      shp_1km_sd   0.89    sd
4   Austin   shp_100m_mean   7.20  mean
5  Chicago   shp_100m_mean   6.25  mean
6   Austin     shp_100m_sd   3.10    sd
7  Chicago     shp_100m_sd   1.11    sd
```

Similarly, we want to know the `metric` column, as you call it, which we can do by splitting that same column but joining the first and second elements.

```py
df['metric'] = df['variable'].str.split('_').str[0:2].transform('_'.join)
df
       City       variable  value  temp_col    metric
0   Austin    shp_1km_mean   5.05  mean   shp_1km
1  Chicago    shp_1km_mean   2.17  mean   shp_1km
2   Austin      shp_1km_sd   1.02    sd   shp_1km
3  Chicago      shp_1km_sd   0.89    sd   shp_1km
4   Austin   shp_100m_mean   7.20  mean  shp_100m
5  Chicago   shp_100m_mean   6.25  mean  shp_100m
6   Austin     shp_100m_sd   3.10    sd  shp_100m
7  Chicago     shp_100m_sd   1.11    sd  shp_100m
```

This is missing the final `_` in the metric name, hope that is OK.

Now you want to convert the `temp_col` back into the two columns (make it wide again?) using `pivot`, and also get rid of that `variable` column that won't be needed anymore

```py
df = df.drop(columns='variable')
df = df.pivot(index=['City','metric'],columns='temp_col',values='value').reset_index()
# if you don't do reset_index() you will have City and Metric as the index, which you may not want.
df
       City    metric  mean    sd
0   Austin   shp_100m  7.20  3.10
1   Austin    shp_1km  5.05  1.02
2  Chicago   shp_100m  6.25  1.11
3  Chicago    shp_1km  2.17  0.89
```

So, all together, you would have

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars='City')
df['temp_col'] = df['variable'].str.split('_').str[2]
df['metric'] = df['variable'].str.split('_').str[0:2].transform('_'.join)
df = df.drop(columns='variable')
df = df.pivot(index=['City','metric'],columns='temp_col',values='value').reset_index()
```